# PHP explode returns array with count 2 but gets undefined offset when accessing second element?

Tags: php, undefined, offset, explode

I'm working with php/mySQL/Apache. I have an array with two positions.

```
print_r($pair) returns Array ( [0] => Maria João [1] => 1 )
```

When I do

```
$pair = explode("-",$b); 
if(count($pair)==2){ 
$investigador = $pair[0]; 
$ponderacao = $pair[1]; }
```

it works.

When I do

```
$pair = explode("-",$b); 
$investigador = $pair[0]; 
$ponderacao = $pair[1];
```

it returns "Undefined offset: 1"

Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you `var_dump` the variable `$b` in your second try ?

Comment: $ponderacao = $pair[1];` 
is this the issue '`' have you noticed it ?

Comment: Do you have a loop around that code that you haven't included in the question? If so, it's likely that not all `pairs` are delimited strings and the check you have in the first example is required.

Comment: As its working for first condition it should work for second condition. And you are testing with same strings in multiple scenario... You have not shared the strings which you are testing with.

Answer (score 0):

During Explode: maybe there is a chance that the string is not containt exact match whatever you given as reference in explode and due to that the notice occur.

try this,

```
$investigador = (isset($pair[0]) && $pair[0]!="")?$pair[0]:"";
$ponderacao = (isset($pair[1]) && $pair[1]!="")?$pair[1]:"";
```

For Example,

> $b = "Maria João-1";

```
<?php
$b = "Maria João-1";
$pair = explode("-",$b); 
echo $pair[0]."<br>";
echo $pair[1]; 
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Maria João
1
```

Now Just change the string nd try again

> $b = "Maria João_1";

```
<?php
$b = "Maria João_1";
$pair = explode("-",$b); 
echo $pair[0]."<br>";
echo $pair[1]; 
?>
```

OUTPUT:

> Maria João_1
>
> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 1 -- at line 12